# Remove all elements which occur in less than 1% and more than 60% of the list

Tags: python, list

If I have this list of strings:

```
['fsuy3,fsddj4,fsdg3,hfdh6,gfdgd6,gfdf5',
'fsuy3,fsuy3,fdfs4,sdgsdj4,fhfh4,sds22,hhgj6,xfsd4a,asr3']
```

(big list)

how can I remove all words which occur in less than 1% and more than 60% of the strings?

Comment: Is a list the only data structure you can use here? How are the strings populated into the list

Comment: The strings are guaranteed to be a comma-separated list of words? And you're interesting in those comma-separated words (e.g. 'fsuy3'), rather than the elements of the list you've shown (e.g., 'fsuy3,fsddj4,...').

Comment: in the tittle you say "occur .. of the list" and in the question body "occur ... of the strings", which one do you want?

Answer (score 8):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
counts = Counter(mylist)
```

and then:

```
newlist = [s for s in mylist if 0.01 < counts[s]/len(mylist) < 0.60]
```

(in Python 2.x use `float(counts[s])/len(mylist)`)

---

If you're talking about the comma-seperated words, then you can use a similar approach:

```
words = [l.split(',') for l in mylist]

counts = Counter(word for l in words for word in l)

newlist = [[s for s in l if 0.01 < counts[s]/len(mylist) < 0.60] for l in words]
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the OP is looking for, but I don't think this is it. It looks like the OP wants to look at the comma-delimited substrings of the list elements.

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward solution

```
occurrences = dict()
for word in words:
  if word not in occurrences:
     occurrences[word] = 1
  else:
     occurrences[word] += 1

result = [word for word in words 0.01 <= occurrences[word] /len(words) <= 0.6]
```

Comment: rather than test if word is in occurences, you can use a default_dict. and rather than a default_dict, you can use a Counter, which does all that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess you want this:

```
    from collections import Counter,Set

# break up by ',' and remove duplicate words on each line
    st = [set(s.split(',')) for s in mylist]

# Count all the words
    count = Counter([word for line in st for word in line])

# Work out which words are allowed
    allowed = [s for s in count if 0.01 < counts[s]/len(mylist) < 0.60]

#For each row in the original list. If the word is allowed then keep it
    result = [[w for w in s.split(',') if w in allowed] for s in mylist]

    print result
```